# Scala Spark Dataframe sum list of json values in the column

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame as given below:

| id | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"a":1}] | [{"d": 3, "e": 4}] |
| 2 | [{"a":2}] | [{"d": 5, "e": 10}] |

I want to obtain the following data frame:

| id | col2_sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 10 |

Datatypes:

```
id:StringType

col1:StringType

col2:StringType
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The logic behind the sum is not clear. How should `col2_sum` be calculated?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `col2_sum = 15` fro `id = 2`?

Comment: I'm sorry it is 15 for id = 2

Answer (score 1):

Convert JSON string into map type using `from_json` then use `aggregate` function to sum the map values:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, """[{"a":1}]""", """[{"d": 3, "e": 4}]"""),
  (2, """[{"a":2}]""", """[{"d": 5, "e": 10}]""")
).toDF("id", "col1", "col2")

val df1 = (df
  .withColumn("col2", from_json(col("col2"), lit("array<map<string,int>>")))
  .withColumn("col2", flatten(expr("transform(col2, x -> map_values(x))")))
  .withColumn("col2_sum", expr("aggregate(col2, 0, (acc, x) -> acc + x)"))
  .drop("col1", "col2")
)

df1.show
//+---+--------+
//| id|col2_sum|
//+---+--------+
//|  1|       7|
//|  2|      15|
//+---+--------+
```

Comment: lit function returns a column type while the from_json expects a struct right?

Comment: @CuriousFreak this is working on Spark 3.0.1. You can alos pass a struct type like this: `ArrayType(MapType(StringType,IntegerType,true),true)` instead of `lit("array<map<string,int>>")`